# Partial migration from xml to json in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activeresource

Currently we are using xml as the mode of transportation to and from our application. So for the new api we create at the server, we want to move to json. When I do 
                 `ActiveResource::Base.format = :json`

This essentially changes mode of transportation from xml to json completely. I don't want to do it completely. I want to do it only for new api.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a class by class basis as follows:

```
class Base < ActiveResource::Base
  self.format = :json
  ...
```

I have seen code which set self.format at the beginning of user defined methods.

```
class Base < ActiveResource::Base
  def all
    self.format = :json
    find(:all)
  end
  ...
```

As suggested by my class name, you also could put the settings in a class that inherits from ActiveResource, and have your classes using the new API inherit from that base class.